# Supporting ROS services in Ignition bridge

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I could find that Ignition supports 'topic' and 'services' in the transport library, but Ignition bridge which is for ROS2 integration only supports 'topic'.
( https://discourse.ros.org/t/thoughts-on-ignition-gazebo-simulator-and-ros2-bridge/16477 )
Is there any way to use services in Ignition bridge? I'm afraid of delay time if I can use only 'topic' message.

[Ignition bridge]
https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ros_ign/blob/ros2/ros_ign_bridge/README.md

[Ignition topic]
https://ignitionrobotics.org/api/transport/11.0/messages.html

[Ignition services]
https://ignitionrobotics.org/api/transport/11.0/services.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27916/supporting-ros-services-in-ignition-bridge/) by [fonawork](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74720/fonawork/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Bridging services will be available soon. See:

- Issue: https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ros_ign/issues/70
- Pull request: https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ros_ign/pull/211

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2022-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fonawork](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74720/fonawork/) on 2022-03-07**:
thank you!